# Am I doing it correctly?

Tags: android, callback, android-alertdialog

I'm learning and remembering Android and I want to understand my mistakes.
This is my confirm/cancel AlertDialog class. Created it in separate class to split code and not put everything in one Activity:

```
public class ConversationAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static Dialog createDialog(Context context) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        builder.setMessage("Continue?")
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User confirms

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

This is my Activity where I show AlertDialog:

```
    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConversationAlertDialog.createDialog(ConversionActivity.this).show();
        }
    });
```

Next I want to create callback so I could write Dialog cancel/confirm behaviour in Activity. This way it will be also easier to use code that is already written in Activity. I am still learning about callbacks so not sure, but I think I should implement interface.

All kind of tips would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is the code I use. I find it quite flexible because you can create several similar dialogs for slightly different tasks. You will need to create a layout file - this gives you a great deal of flexibility on function and style.

My layout file is `fragment_ok_cancel_dialog`.

In the Activity that calls the dialog you will need to implement the Listener.

```
implements OkCancelDialogFragment.OkCancelDialogListener
```

Another advantage is with my code you can change the title and the message to fit the needs of any Activity.

```
private void callMyDialog(){ 
    //Customize the title and message as needed
    String title = "This is my dialog title";
    String mess = "This is my dialog message";
    OkCancelDialogFragment dialog = OkCancelDialogFragment.newInstance(title, mess);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "OkCancelDialogFragment2");
}
```

Now you need to implement the dialog callback in the Activity that calls the DialogFragment.

```
@Override
public void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit) {
    if(submit){
        // Do something positive
    }
    else{
        // Do something negative
    }
}
```

Now the code for the `DialogFragment`:

```
public class OkCancelDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    Context context = null;

    private String title;
    private String message;
    private boolean submitData = false;

    private OkCancelDialogListener mListener;

    public OkCancelDialogFragment() {
    }

    public static OkCancelDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        OkCancelDialogFragment fragment = new OkCancelDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            title = getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE);
            message = getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveIntsanceState){

        context = getActivity();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ok_cancel_dialog, null, false);
        final TextView titleView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        final TextView messView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

        titleView.setText(title);
        messView.setText(message);

        builder.setView(rootView)
//                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button_dialog_title, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        submitData = true;
                        if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
                        mListener.onFinishOkCancelDialog(submitData);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        submitData = false;
                        if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
                        mListener.onFinishOkCancelDialog(submitData);
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            if(mListener == null) mListener = (OkCancelDialogListener) context;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OkCancelDialogListener {
        void onFinishOkCancelDialog(boolean submit);
    }

}
```

Please note that `.setTitle(title)` is valid for API 23 or higher (or maybe API 21 or higher?).

Answer (score 1):

Create an Interface in `ConversationAlertDialog` class.

```
public interface onActionSelect{
void onOkSelect();
void onCancelSelect();
}
```

Implement it on Activity and pass it's reference to `ConversationAlertDialog` class. Then call from dialog like that.

```
  // For Positive Button Click
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    // User confirms
    if(mCallBack != null) mCallBack.onOkSelect()
 }

  // For Negative  Button Click
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    // User confirms
    if(mCallBack != null) mCallBack.onCancelSelect()
 }
```

You will be notified in MainActivity when positive or negative button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ConversationAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private onMyEvent event;
    public void setMyEvent(onMyEvent e)
    {
        this.event=e;
    }
    public static Dialog createDialog(Context context) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        builder.setMessage("Continue?")
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User confirms
                        if(null!=event)
                        {
                            event.ok();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        if(null!=event)
                        {
                            event.cancel();
                        }
                        // User cancelled
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
    public interface onMyEvent{
        void ok();
        void cancel();
    }
}

buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Dialog  dialog=ConversationAlertDialog.createDialog(ConversionActivity.this);
        dialog.setMyEvent(new onMyEvent{....})
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```